# Wordpress multisite theme calling master site url with $template_url

Tags: wordpress, themes, multisite

I have a theme that appears to be loading some css/javascript from the master site url, this is causing some problems.

For example the two Jquery load fine on the site url, but the bootstrap are not loading as they are trying to pull from a url they cant access.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://live-site.co.uk/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://live-site.co.uk/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//internal-site.co.uk/live/wp-content/themes/live-site-1/bootstrap.min.js?ver=1.0.159'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//internal-site.co.uk/live/wp-content/themes/live-site-1/script.js?ver=1.0.159'></script>
```

Ive gone through the template and found in the functions, where these are called using wp_register_script and wp_enque_script, they get the path using $template_url which is created from get_bloginfo()

```
 $template_url = str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', get_bloginfo('template_url', 'display'));

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', false, array(), $version, 'all' );

wp_register_script("theme-bootstrap", $template_url . '/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), $version);
wp_enqueue_script("theme-bootstrap");

wp_register_script("theme-script", $template_url . '/script.js', array('jquery', 'theme-bootstrap'), $version);
wp_enqueue_script("theme-script");
```

Is there a reason that this get_bloginfo url is causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the line

```
$template_url = str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', get_bloginfo('template_url', 'display'));
```

to

```
$template_url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
```

get_bloginfo('template_url') doesnt recognise child themes, and although this isn't a child theme, it is a sub site, so possibly that is why it was loading the master site url. get_stylesheet_directory recognises child sites and so uses the full url of the site you are in, so fixed my problem. There may be more elegant solutions.

Im guessing that sub sites in multi site are handled similar to child themes in some respects when enqeueing assets